# evaluation of double derivative Munkres analysis on manifolds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $F:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^2$, with $F(0,0)=0$ and $DF(0,0)=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$.

Let $G:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by the equation $$G(x,y,z)=F(x+2y+3z-1, x^3+y^2-z^2).$$

1. Note that $G(-2,3,-1)=F(0,0)=0$. Show that one can solve the equation $G(x,y,z)=0$ for $z$, say $z=g(x,y)$, for $(x,y)$ in a neighborhood $B$ of $(-2,3)$, such that $g(-2,3)=-1$.
2. Find $Dg(-2,3)$.
3. If $D_1D_1F=3$ and $D_1D_2F=-1$ and $D_2D_2F=5$ at $(0,0)$, find $D_2D_1g(-2,3)$.

I was able to solve $1$ and $2$..

Define $h(x,y,z)=(x+2y+3z-1,x^3+y^2-z^2)$, then $G=F\circ h$, so by Chain Rule, $DG=DF(h(x,y,z))Dh(x,y,z)$.

Since $Dh=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
3x^2 & 2y & -2z \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$DG(-2,3,-1)=\begin{bmatrix}
38 & 22 & 12 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

So $\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}(-1)=12\neq 0$.
Hence by the Implicit Function Theorem, we can find such $g$ and $B$.

We have  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}+Dg(-2,3)=0$$

So, $38+22+12 Dg(-2,3)=0$ i.e., $Dg(-2,3)=-5$

I am  not sure how to do third part.
 I would appreciate some help on this problem.